# Issue selecting table with Selenium webdriverJs + Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, typescript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Im trying to use sendKeys('text'); to send text to an input field inside of a  tag with the below code:

```
this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('table:last tr:last td:first input')).sendKeys('button');
this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('table:last tr:last td:nth-of-type(1) input:nth-of-type(1)')).sendKeys('button');
```

The DOM looks like the following:

[image]

When running the code, the following error is produced:

```
InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
```

I'm running  "selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0" also in my environment.

Any ideas how i can use sendKeys(' '); to enter text into an input field?

UPDATED SCREENSHOT:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by sendKeys to table? also i see no table in the DOM you shared. From what you have shared, i can only assume that you want to actually send keys to the input field inside that <td> tag. is this correct?

Comment: Sorry yes, use sendKeys to an input field inside the <td> tag.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Can you give the html code around the table tag,The screenshot you give only focus on the input box inside td. I want use ancestor of tr in css locator to make the locator more strict and accurate.

Comment: you type wrong the Pseudo Element,  :last should be :last-child,  :first should be :first-child

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to send a value to the input field:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('tr.ng-scope td input.ng-dirty')).sendKeys('someText');
```

please be advised that this selector is based on what i see from the attached screenshot, if this doesnt work then might want to see a bigger screenshot of the entire table to adjust.

Comment: Tried the above and it did not work, here is the error: 
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"tr.ng-scope td input.ng-dirty"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)